# Disable "Organize Desktop by Name"?

Tags: icons, gui

When you right-click on the desktop you get some options including "Organize Desktop by Name". I read on another post that the options cannot be changed.

However, I have messed up my desktop a couple of times by mis-clicking on this option when I am actually trying to "Open in Terminal" and I was wondering if even though the option cannot be changed if it can be disabled or if it is possible to remap it to do something else?